# How to define a pointer to a structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I know this is a very basic problem, but I cannot move forward without it and its not clearly explained elsewhere.

Why is this programming giving me so many errors of undeclared identifier? I have declared it, though.

These are the error i am getting.

```
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
Error   3   error C2065: 'ptr' : undeclared identifier
Error   4   error C2065: 'contactInfo' : undeclared identifier
Error   5   error C2059: syntax error : ')'
Error   15  error C2223: left of '->number' must point to struct/union
```

and more...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct contactInfo
{
    int number;
    char id;
}ContactInfo;


void main()
{

    char ch;
    printf("Do you want to dynamically etc");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    fflush(stdin);


        struct contactInfo nom,*ptr;
        ptr=(contactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo));

    nom.id='c';
    nom.number=12;
    ptr->id=nom.id;
    ptr->number=nom.number;
    printf("Number -> %d\n ID -> %c\n",ptr->number,ptr->id);

}
```

Comment: Never call `fflush` on `stdin` - it's UB.

Comment: maybe you should read the C book with more attention

Comment: @PaulR why so? I've read that whenever you need to take two input from unser using scanf you do a fflush to remove the \n in the pipeline?

Comment: @shashlearner: `fflush` is only valid for output or update streams - use `fpurge` for input streams, or just call `getchar()` to discard an unwanted character.

Comment: @PaulR ok. But still the code is faulty. I have removed the typecast and used sizeof *ptr, still there are 20 errors!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct contactInfo
{
    int number;
    char id;
}ContactInfo;
```

This code defines 2 things:

1. a *type* named `ContactInfo`
2. a `struct` named `contactInfo`

Notice the difference of the `c` and `C`!

In your code you are using a mixed combination of both, which is allowed (although confusing IMHO).

If you use the `struct` variant you need to explicitly use `struct contactInfo`. For the other variant (`ContactInfo`) you *must* to omit the `struct` part as it is part of the type definition alteady.

So be careful with both different definitions of your structure. Best would be to only use either one of the variants.

---

I do not have Visual Studio at hand, but the following (corrected) code compiles with gcc properly without any warnings:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct contactInfo
{
    int number;
    char id;
}ContactInfo;


void main()
{
    ContactInfo nom,*ptr;
    ptr=malloc(2*sizeof(ContactInfo));    
}
```

(I left out the not so interesting/unmodified parts of the code)

Comment: i tried and its not working. I think there are other problems as well?

Comment: I added a fixed version of your code that compiles properly with gcc to my answer to show the required corrections

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
ptr=(contactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo));
```

is wrong, there's no type called `contactInfo`.

There's a `struct contactInfo`, which is `typedef`:d as `ContactInfo`. C is case-sensitive (and you must include the `struct` unlike how it works in C++).

Also note that the quoted line is better written as:

```
ptr = malloc(2 * sizeof *ptr);
```

Since [casting the return value of `malloc()` is a bad idea in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169), I removed the cast. Also, repeating the type is a bad idea since it makes the risk of introducing error greater, so I removed that as well.

Note that `sizeof *ptr` means "the size of the the type that `ptr` points at" and is a very handy thing.

Comment: but if i don't typecast malloc, will it not return char type?

Comment: Ok so i removed the typecast, but still its showing me the same errors. I am using VS 2010 and have changed the compiler to c\tc
i still dont get what's the problem here @unwind . thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ptr=(contactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo));
```

with

```
ptr=malloc(2*sizeof(struct contactInfo));
```

Comment: I tried but its still not working. Is the VS 2010 compiler screwing it up? almost all the errors are pointing to the ptr=(contactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo)); line
also removing the typecast adds more error to the program :/

Comment: @akp: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: OK - if you fix your answer I'll happily remove the down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

C is a case sensitive language.

`ptr=(contactInfo)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo));`

which should be:

`ptr=malloc(2*sizeof(ContactInfo));`

Comment: `contactInfo` and `ContactInfo` are 2 different things. So besides case-sensitivity, this is something to keep in mind!

Comment: I agree, contactInfo is a struct tag, ContactInfo is a typedef of that struct.. if I am right @Veger

Comment: That is right, hence my comment that case-sensitivity is not the only problem here.

Answer (score -1):

```
struct contactInfo nom,*ptr;
ptr=(contactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(contactInfo));
```

here you are using contactInfo to typcast where as it should be struct contactInfo. and as you have typedef it into ContactInfo you can use that also.

```
    struct contactInfo nom,*ptr;
    ptr=(ContactInfo*)malloc(2*sizeof(ContactInfo));
```